# docusignapi c# split signing experience

Tags: c#, split, docusignapi, signing

We have an application that creates document envelopes to be signed using the official DocuSign C# client 
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client

What I am looking for is a way to split the signing experience into two groups. 
Group A (reps), we want them to create an account with a required two-factor authentication method. 
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-two-step-verification

Group B (clients), we want them to sign in without creating an account but rather authenticate via Lexus Nexus ID check. 
https://www.docusign.com/partner/docusign-id-check-powered-by-lexisnexis-risk-solutions

Has anybody done something like this?

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Comment: I have below queries on this, are Group A users members of your DS Account? do you want to send same envelope to these two set of users?

Comment: Other qs is, are Group A (reps) users have same email domain like email@yourcompanyemaildomain.com?

Comment: Group A are new users , know to the application but not to DS. The groups have their own email. We separate them out in our database. Thanks in advance  Amit K Bist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most appropriate solution for your usecase will be using `DocuSign SSO` for `GroupA` users, GroupB users are normal signers so you need to just apply KBA check for GroupB.

To implement DocuSign SSO, you need to have your all groupA users in same email domain, which will be your company email domain like acmecorp.com, then you need to claim this email domain in DocuSign. Now in your domain settings in DocuSign, you will select `Always require login when opening envelopes` option, if this option is selected then GroupA users have to login first to your IdP, and then its your IdP call to either create that user in DocuSign or not (if that user does not exist in DocuSign). Also, you can implement multi-factor authentication in your IdP as well. Now IdP can create that user in DocuSign using Just-in-time provisioning if that user does not exist in DocuSign. You can find more details related to DocuSign SSO at [Org Admin Implementation Guide](https://support.docusign.com/guides/org-admin-guide).

With this type of implementation, you can even restrict any GroupA user if any time in future that user leaves the company then you can prevent their access to DocuSign by restricting them from your IdP and everything is controlled from your IdP.